# How to close runtime permission dialog in OnDestroy?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-permissions

I know that there are multiple questions regarding this, but they are unanswered and I'm starting to think that it is not possible, but I'll go ahead and ask.

I'm requesting Runtime Permissions in `OnCreate()` and everything is working fine. But I also have screen orientation enabled, and the user may decide to go from portrait to landscape(maybe by accident) and in that case, by the Android lifecycle  `OnDestroy` followed by `OnCreate` will be called. This should be fine in any situation, but apparently, the Runtime Permissions dialogues are still showing on the screen and they are not dismissed by `OnDestroy`. This will result in some strange behaviour with having multiple request runtime permissions dialogues and multiple  `OnRequestPermissionsResult` waiting for them.

Is there any way to actually get rid of them on OnDestroy, or should I just create a new Activity, keep it only in PortraitMode and ask for permissions there?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve